# Transform an http.get response json instance of Typescript Model

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance, angular7, http-get

I haven't found a solid answer on this question:
How do I transform my JSON response from an HTTP.get request into an instance of my Typescript object?

Set the stage:

```
CLASS =====================
export interface IMyClass {
  myClassId: number;
  myClassName: string;
  myClassDescription: string;
}

export class MyClass implements IMyClass {
  public myClassId: number;
  public myClassName: string;
  public myClassDescription: string;

  constructor(
    myClassId: number;
    myClassName: string;
    myClassDescription: string;
  ) {
    this.myClassId = myClassId
    this.myClassName = myClassName
    this.myClassDescription = myClassName    
  }
}


SERVICE===============
  public getMyClassById(id: number): Observable<MyClass> {
    return this.http.get<MyClass>(`${this.apiEndpoint}/myClassId?myClassID=${id}`)
  }
```

I'm trying to figure out how to do this without leveraging the full constructor, because my real Model has around 12 properties. I have tried pipe => mapping the response as MyClass and that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: My preference is to stick to interfaces to define the returned structures from api calls and not use concrete classes at all. I only ever create a new class instance for a model if there is behavior I want to associate directly with it which is rare. This reduces the amount of code and your api call is simply `return this.http.get<IMyClass>(url);`

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to figure out how to do this without leveraging the full constructor,

You are looking for a deserialization (also called hydration) library.

The one I can recommend is https://github.com/mobxjs/serializr as it supports TypeScript

## My thoughts

Personally [I prefer to keep with manual assignments](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QFTL0HgNoaQ), its more code, but saves you from *magic* bugs.

Comment: I was on a team at some point where this was done on the fly by handling the response, but it was a while ago and I cant remember how it was done.

Answer (score 0):

You can short code everything in the constructor:

```
export interface IMyClass {
    myClassId: number;
    myClassName: string;
    myClassDescription: string;
}

export class MyClass implements IMyClass {

    constructor(
        public myClassId: number,
        public myClassName: string,
        public myClassDescription: string
    ) {

    }
}
```

You don't need the public and private ones, just public in the constructor.

I guess the `;` in the constructor it's something that you pasted wrong.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I pasted in the semi colons.  This is a good tip, I'm not sure it helps with my current problem though.

Comment: What's your current problem then? You have to declare somewhere what your class uses or go for interfaces instead. You can do what you want with interfaces instead without typing anything more.